# Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[glusterfs]'

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, glusterfs

I am running the chef-client 12.4.1 and trying to install the GlusterFS using a cookbook.The GlusterFS version is 3.6.2. Whenever I am trying to bootstrap an ec2 instance using knife ec2 with gluster cookbook, its showing the error as below. I am not sure why its showing the error at the bootstrap time:

> Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[glusterfs]'

One thing I notice is that if I login to ec2 and adding gluster cookbook from chef server to node and then run chef-client, it is getting installed without any errors. My AMI is RHEL 6.1 and posted blow is the error log.

Logs :

```
Chef::Exceptions::Exec: yum_package[glusterfs] (schl_system::gluster_client_install line 11) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec:  returned 1, expected 0
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:157:in `handle_command_failures'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1019:in `yum_command'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1134:in `install_package'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:82:in `block in action_install'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:149:in `converge_by'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:80:in `action_install'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:114:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:625:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/client.rb:433:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/client.rb:500:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/client.rb:199:in `block in run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/client.rb:193:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/client.rb:193:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/application.rb:208:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:312:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:304:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:304:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/lib/chef/application.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Maybe it is getting installed without admin privileges? It seems like 'exec' returns error code so it is from package, not from your recipe. Check if  you have permissions on nodes.

Comment: I tried with admin privileges too, but its showing the same.